# Libvirt migration hostname

Tags: libvirt

I've set up two libvirt nodes with the following hostnames:

- mycompany-hv-01.example.tld
- mycompany-hv-02.example.tld

The names are declared in a public DNS and resolvable (public IPs).

When I try to migrate a guest from one host to the other:

```
root@mycompany-hv-02:~# virsh migrate prout qemu+ssh://mycompany-hv-01.example.tld/system --offline --persistent
error: internal error: hostname on destination resolved to localhost, but migration requires an FQDN
```

The error is the same when I try a live migration.

I know this is not exactly the same error, but I tried the advices on [this page](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Migration_fails_with_%22Unable_to_resolve_address%22_error). My DNS are already working, so I tried to force resolution by adding entries to my `/etc/hosts` on both hosts, but that doesn't work.

The following workaround works:

```
virsh migrate prout qemu+ssh://mycompany-hv-02.example.tld/system tcp://mycompany-hv-02.example.tld --offline --persistent
```

I tried to manually define `migration_host` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` but I got the error:

```
configuration file syntax error: migration_host must not be the address of the local machine: mycompany-hv-01.example.tld
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

> configuration file syntax error: migration_host must not be the address of the local machine: mycompany-hv-01.example.tld

This means that libvirt tried to resolve  "mycompany-hv-01.example.tld" and found that it resolves to 127.0.0.1

This is arguably a bug in libvirt, because only the migration source host needs to be able to resolve that address to a non-localhost IP address. It is fine if the host where you configured  qemu.conf has it resolving to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Well, `dig mycompany-hv-01.example.tld` gives the public IP of the host, so I don't know why it says it resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Most likely is that /etc/hosts on the host itself has a line mapping it to 127.0.0.1.   IOW, other hosts would resolve to its public IP correctly, but this host would resolve to its own loopback addr.

Comment: You're right, I had the following line in my /etc/hosts :
`127.0.1.1      mycompany-hv-01 mycompany-hv-01.example.tld`
on both hosts.
But I commented it out, and it's still the same error (event after restarting libvirt).